# I'm getting an error in WordPress when I'm try to include a class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, include

I've to do a search form into my WordPress into a specific table in the database. So, I create a DAO class where I make the query and I save the result into a DTO class. To do that, I create an abstract class where I make the conection to my database and then made the query. Something like this:

```
abstract class abstract_dao {
    protected $conectorbd;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conectorbd = new conectorbd();
    } 
}
```

Where I make the conection, and then I've the `cancion_dao.php`, something like this:

```
define('RUTA', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/");
require_once 'abstract_dao.php';
require_once '../db/dto/cancion_dto.php';

class cancion_dao extends abstract_dao {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getCanciones($consulta) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM canciones WHERE trackName LIKE '%" . $this->conectorbd->escapar_cadena($consulta) . "%'";          

        $vuelta = $this->conectorbd->ejecutar_query($sql);
        $dto = null;
        while ($datos = $this->conectorbd->bd_fetch_array($vuelta)) {                
            $dto = new cancion_dto($datos['id'], $datos['trackName'], $datos['artistName'], $datos['albumName'], $datos['category']);
        }
        return $dto;
    }

}
```

I know it's not 100% correct. But for my question I think it's enough. For more information I have `abstract_dao` and `cancion_dao` in the same directory. I have this:

```
wp-content/db
      ---------conectordb.php
      ---------/dao
      -------------/abstract_dao.php
      -------------/cancion_dao.php
      ---------/dto
      -------------/cancion_dto.php
```

So, all of this information is to clarify my situation. And this is the problem:

When I try to search something and I call to my function `getCanciones()` I get this error:

```
require_once(/db/dto/cancion_dto.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 4.
```

Then, I try with the full URL with:

```
define('RUTA', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/");
```

And I've this new message error:

```
require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

I try with other options like using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, `dirname( __FILE__ )`, etc. But the only that I get are messages error.

I don't know how to resolve this and I hope someone can help. **How can I include files which aren't in the same directory?**

Thank you and sorry about my english skills!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use  `get_template_directory()` 
**@return string Template directory path.**

```
// it will work when you have structure like project.com/wp-content/themes/yourThemeName/db/dto/cancion_dto.php
include_once(get_template_directory()."/db/dto/cancion_dto.php");

// and For use  the function from your class
$cancion_Class  = new cancion_dao();
$cancion_Class->getCanciones($consulta);
```